# Which sentence is more correct and which form of verb should be used for the last sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

Which sentence is more correct and which form of verb should be used for the last sentence?

> **The energy of** sample A and **the energy of** sample B increase.
>
> **The energy of** sample A and **that of** B increase.
>
> **The energy of** each sample A and B increase.
>
> **The energy of** sample A and B **increase(s)**.

Comment: You missed out *The **energies** of **samples** A and B **increase***, which might well be the *most* idiomatically acceptable and "correct" version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions can be simplified by identifying the subject(s).
1. energy and energy increase
2. energy and that increase
3. (not quite grammatical)
4. energy increases
(But note that if the energies of A and B are independent, 4 would be better as
4a. The energies of sample A and sample B increase.)

Comment: do you mean that 3rd sentence is grammatically incorrect? it is possible that the 2nd sentence be written as "the energy of sample A and of B increase." ?

Comment: Yes, the 3rd doesn't fit together. No, I think that suggestion for 2 would have to be "energies of sample A and of B increase."